# Difficulties using Geb to enable a disabled control using .removeAttr()

Tags: jquery, geb

Firstly, I am a Geb newbie and also fairly new to web technology in general, that said my issue is ... I am trying to enable the following input element:

`<input class="span6 offset2" id="uploadFile" value="" placeholder="Select File" disabled="disabled" />`

Within geb I have the following:

**uploadFileField.removeAttr(disabled)** ... where *uploadFileField equates to { $('input', id:"uploadFile") }*

but I am getting the following error:

*java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Value of 'disabled' attribute can only be checked for the following elements: button, input, option, select, textarea.*

**Question** - Do you think the message is telling me that the ‘disabled’ attribute can only be checked? – i.e cannot be removed?, otherwise - what am I doing wrong? any suggestions will be deeply appreciated.

Comment: have you placed quotes around the text disabled? I.e. uploadFileField.removeAttr('disabled')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put the attribute name in quotes - it should be a string literal(`"disabled"`) and not a variable literal(`disabled`). I suspect that your code is part of a module definition. Because `Module` implements `Navigator` and there is a `isDisabled()` method on that interface your code got resolved as an attempt to retrieve `disabled` property on the base navigator of your module. That navigator holds something else than a form element and thus the error you're seeing is being thrown.

The error message could definitely be more helpful and informative therefore I [created a ticket to improve it](https://jira.codehaus.org/browse/GEB-345).

Comment: Sorry, only just seen this. It didn't work with "disabled" initially and I forget why, but I think Erdi's concise description sums it up nicely .. many thanks